# Showing that orbit of a point element forms a partition.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

> **Question:**
>   Let G be a permutation of a set S. Prove that the orbits of the members of S constitute a partition of S.

The orbit of a point element s in S under the group G is the set

$$Orb_{G}\left ( s \right )=\left \{ \phi\left ( s \right )\mid \phi \in G \right \}$$

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Here is a big hint: an equivalence relation on a set naturally determines a partition of that set into equivalence classes. What equivalence relation could you put on $S$ whose equivalence classes are exactly the orbits of $S$ under the action of $G$?

Answer (score 1):

Directly:

Obviously for each $s\in S$, $s$ is in some orbit. Namely, you have $s=e(s)$ where $e$ is the identity of $G$, so $s\in Orb_G(s)$. This shows that $S\subseteq \cup\{Orb_G(s)\mid s\in S\}$.

All that remains is to show that for elements $s,t\in S$, either $Orb_G(s)\cap Orb_G(t)=\emptyset$ or else $Orb_G(s)= Orb_G(t)$.

If $u\in Orb_G(s)\cap Orb_G(t)$, then $u=\phi(s)=\phi'(t)$ for some $\phi, \phi'\in G$. With this final string of equalities, you can demonstrate $s=\phi''(t)$ for some $\phi''\in G$. Do you see what $\phi''$ works?

Once $t\in Orb_G(s)$, obviously $Orb_G(t)\subseteq Orb_G(s)$. By symmetry the reverse containment holds as well.

So the set of orbits is a pairwise disjoint collection of sets covering $S$, a.k.a. a partition of $S$.